# Центрирование background в css при наличии position

Tags: css

Добрый день. Хочу узнать как можно отцентрировать бэк, если в коде уже есть position, и margin: auto - не работает.

```
.content{ 
width: 980px; 
height: 458px; 
background: url(background.png); 
position: absolute; 
z-index: 3; 
top: 700px; 
margin-left: 18.7%; 
}
```

При уменьшении экрана, бэк, конечно же, съезжает, хочется, чтобы он располагался всегда по центру. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это грамотно реализовать.

Comment: Что значит «отцентрировать»? Относительно чего? Что должно получиться?

Comment: Относительно экрана. Центрированный объекта, независимо от размеров экрана.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: Он не будет скроллится, но по центру не будет.

Comment: position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -490px;

Comment: Вы мой спаситель! Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1):

```
.content{ 
  /* Ваш код */
  backround-position: center; 
}
```

[Описание здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position)

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает такой метод.